Prisma ORM table generated with wrong name
I am using Prisma ORM in an Express application. I have a table named "sessions" in plural and a definition in singular mapped to the name of the table using @@map, like this
model Session {
  sid String  @db.VarChar(100) @id 
  sess Json
  expire DateTime @default(now()) 

  @@map(name: "sessions")
}

But still, when I tried to use it, it showed me:
error: relation "session" does not exist
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/pg-pool@3.7.0_pg@8.13.0/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:45:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async PGStore._asyncQuery (/usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/connect-pg-simple@10.0.0/node_modules/connect-pg-simple/index.js:322:21)

I have generated the client several times, but still. I haven't found any explanation, and I could not locate where the code is generated so I could not figure it out why my Session object is not mapping to "sessions" instead of "session"
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Note:
I am using node 20.18.0,  express 4.21.1, prisma 5.21.1, prisma-client 5.21.1
By the way, I have generated the client and create the tables. This is not a problem of "oh I forgot to create the tables on the db" at all. As a matter of fact, there is another model, User, mapped to the table users the same way, and it works perfectly.

Okay, I figured it out. The problem was not related to Prisma but with express-session. express-session handles a table with the name "session", no sessions. I do not know if it is possible to change the name, but I do not see a reason to do it. So I simply changed the name on migrations, generated the tables again, removed the mapping, and it worked.
